# Why do we have to remove all other cards once a dragon was hatched?

Tags: untagged

So me and my little one just heard about dragomino so we reviewed a presentation of that game.

It was said, once a player finds a hatchling in a flipped egg, the cards get removed and a new turn starts. So my little one smart as she is noted here this sounds really frustrating, and I had to agree. So I was wondering: what happens if we instead of starting a new turn once a hatchling is found, instead we only end turns once everyone has had their turn. Would this disturb the games ballance?

Or what is the reason for the turns being aborted, once a player found a hatchling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [rules](https://www.blueorangegames.com/administrator/components/com_bogames/files/rules/ccdafb9e0bdffa0ce3f3263be02dbee3-DRAGOMINO-US-RULES-US.pdf)

> After each player has carried out their 2 steps (1: Pick a domino, 2: Match dominoes to collect eggs), turn over and discard the remaining dominoes, if any, then take 4 new dominoes from the box and place these in the center of the table, face-up.  The player holding the Mommy Dragon is the first player to start the next round

Nowhere in the rules does it say anything about immediately beginning a new round once a player finds a dragon so I'm unsure where you got that from.  If you happen to find dragons then that simply increases your current total number of points and nothing more.  On the other hand, if a player finds a cracked empty egg-shell the player will take the Mommy Dragon piece which will become relevant for deciding who begins the next round. (*The Mommy Dragon piece may be taken multiple times by multiple players in a round if multiple players found cracked eggs.  It only matters who holds the piece at the beginning of the next round*).  The current round still completes as normal regardless of whether or not any dragon or cracked egg was found.

All players will end up having played the same total number of turns.

Comment: We atched a review of the game where the person presenting the game claimed it was that way.

Comment: Attached it where?  In any event, either you misinterpreted what was said, or the person who made the video got it wrong and didn't do their research (which for a game targeted at small children with a two page rule book reflects very poorly on them)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKGCXu-2tqA It was this one. I didnt add it to the OP cause it is in german, tho.